# Create empty queryset by default in django form fields

Tags: django, django-forms

I have this fields in form:

```
city = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="city", queryset=MyCity.objects.all())
district = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="district", queryset=MyDistrict.objects.all())
area = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="area", queryset=MyArea.objects.all())
```

district comes from click on city and area comes from click on area. With  `queryset=MyDistrict.objects.all()` and `queryset=MyArea.objects.all()` form will be very heavy. How can I make querysets empty by default?

Answer (score 611, accepted):

You can have an empty queryset by doing this:

```
MyModel.objects.none()
```

Although i don't know how are you going to use that form, you can put that as your field's queryset in order to get what you need...

You can find more information [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#none)

Comment: In the use case that your queryset changes in your view based on url parameters. Then in your view you set the correct queryset like so:
edit_form.fields["asset"].queryset = Asset.objects.filter(location_id=location_id)

Comment: What if I don't have a model, I'm just doing a `values_list('something', flat=True)`?

Answer (score 3):

@radtek's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243559/create-empty-queryset-by-default-in-django-form-fields#comment36297084_11244370) should be an answer as it is useful in similar scenarios but with different approach than the accepted answer.

> If your queryset changes with the url in your view.

I am extending the answer with example as I used:

```
def my_view(request):
    ...
    form = YourForm(initial={'field1':value1, 'field2':value2})
    form.fields['field3'].queryset = YourModel.objects.filter('foo'=bar)
```